# How to detect the type of widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

This should be a stupid question. I am just curious and could not find the answer on my own.

E.g. I define in PyQt5 some widgets:

```
self.lbl = QLabel("label")
self.btn = QPushButton("click")
self.txt = QLineEdit("text")
```

Is there any method to detect what kind of widget the `self.lbl`, `self.btn`, or `self.txt` are?

I could imagine: by detecting the widget type, the input is `self.lbl`, the output should be `QLabel`... Or something like this.

I have only found the isWidgetType() method. But it is not what I want to have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several ways to get the name of the widget:

- using `__class__`:

---

```
print(self.lbl.__class__.__name__)
```

- using QMetaObject:

---

```
print(self.lbl.metaObject().className())
```

These previous methods return a string with the name of the class, but if you want to verify if an object belongs to a class you can use `isinstance()`:

```
is_label = isinstance(self.lbl, QLabel)
```

Another option is to use `type()` but it is not recommended, if you want to get more information about `isinstance()` and `type()` read the following: [What are the differences between type() and isinstance()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the standard Python means of checking an object type:

```
print(type(self.lbl))
print(isinstance(self.lbl, QLabel)
```